# How much is Stan Lee paid for his cameos in MCU films?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, acting-career, cameo, stan-lee

I have done some research for a question similar to this (but fundamentally different from it) on SF&F, but I couldn't come up with any specific numbers.

The Screen Actors Guild requires that actors be paid for their time, and the rates depend on:

- Whether the part includes lines
- How many days the actor is on set
- Whether the actor is prominent in his or her scenes

And a number of other factors.

Stan Lee appears in most MCU films, usually speaking a line or two, and always in a prominent place onscreen.  I'm not sure whether he's an SAG member.

### Do we know how much he is paid for these cameos, assuming (as it seems safe to do) that he is paid at all?

If such information is unavailable, can we hypothesize about how much a person should make in roles along these?

Comment: this has been asked and answered here: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/18152/does-stan-lee-get-paid-for-his-appearances-in-marvel-movies

Comment: @BamfTheNightAway - No, it hasn't, as my answer there shows.  The questions are similar but different, as I said in this question.

Comment: I don't see your answer or comments on SF&F

Comment: @BamfTheNightAway - Derp. I should have mentioned that I answered it with my main account, Wad Cheber.

Comment: Stan Lee is payed in No-Prizes....the same kind he used to give out. :)

Answer (score 3):

According to [CNN](https://edition.cnn.com/2012/05/14/showbiz/movies/stan-lee-avengers/index.html), Lee said,

> I hate to admit this, but I do not share in the movie's profits. I just share in the interviews, in the glamour, in the people saying, "Wow, I love that movie, Stan" -- but I'm not a participant in the profits.

Also checkout around 6:58 of the video.

And his net worth is estimated to be anywhere from $50 to $200 million already.

And it is safe to say it's usually honorary but it is rumored that he is paid for the spoken part.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to [movies.se]! It'd be good if you can add the link to that interview.

Comment: Always remember to add your source of information, as I did with your answer just now.

Comment: @Aj Thank you. I couldn't find the exact source but I found this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u_29DHdH_ig Checkout around 6:58 of the video. He said it himself to Lary King. :)

Comment: @uservs301 you can add youtube link in answers too they are also playable

Comment: @AnkitSharma Oh! New here. I will once go through all the how, what, where of the comment formatting as well. Thank you once again.